# Create hyperlink over img, focus outlining only the link

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a link anchor on img like this

```
<a href="xxx.html"><img src="image.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"/></a>
```

Tabbing over image, the outline only show border around the link (which is a line height) instead of the whole image. Tried the css outline-offset but it'll stretch the width of outline.

Is there any way I can set the outline on the complete image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set anchor tag to `display:inline-block`

```
a{display:inline-block}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
a:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/any" width="100px" height="100px" />
</a>
```